# Xamarin.iOS send data from iOS project to Notification Service Extension

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In Xamarin.iOS project I am intercepting the push notification and I want to modify it before presenting to the user according to some conditions that are accessible (stored preferences) in the iOS project. How can I pass data from iOS project to the Notification Service Extension, and potentially the other way around as well? Or maybe more precisely, how can I access user preferences from the Xamarin.Forms project in the iOS Notification Service Extension project?

I am mostly interested in accessing user preferences that I stored using Xamarin.Essentials

This is the template code for the Notification Service Extension:

```
namespace NotifServiceExtension
{
    [Register("NotificationService")]
    public class NotificationService : UNNotificationServiceExtension
    {
        Action<UNNotificationContent> ContentHandler { get; set; }
        UNMutableNotificationContent BestAttemptContent { get; set; }

        protected NotificationService(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        }

        public override void DidReceiveNotificationRequest(UNNotificationRequest request, Action<UNNotificationContent> contentHandler)
        {
            ContentHandler = contentHandler;
            BestAttemptContent = (UNMutableNotificationContent)request.Content.MutableCopy();

            // Modify the notification content here...
            var region = Preferences.Get("region_key", "error");   // I cannot access preferences this way   

             BestAttemptContent.Title = string.Format("{0}[modified]", BestAttemptContent.Title);          


            ContentHandler(BestAttemptContent);
        }

        public override void TimeWillExpire()
        {
            // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
            // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.

            ContentHandler(BestAttemptContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is by exposing a method on the Xamarin.Forms `App` class.

In the **App.xaml.cs** file add a new method like this:

```
public string GetUserRegion()
{
    return Preferences.Get("region_key", "error");
}
```

and inside your `NotificationService` class you can get the region like this:

```
var region = (Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current as App)?.GetUserRegion();
```

Comment: will give that a try as soon as possible. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @FreedomOfSpeech where you able achieve with this method ?